# opencv by python erorr

Tags: python, opencv, cascade-classifier

I got an error message when I execute the python code mentioned below:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:\Users\smart-26\Desktop\예제\face.py", line 28, in
>
> faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(grayframe, 1.1, 3, 0, (30, 30))
>
> cv2.error: D:\Build\OpenCV\opencv->
>
> 3.2.0\modules\objdetect\src\cascadedetect.cpp:1681: error: (-215) !empty() in
>
> function cv::CascadeClassifier::detectMultiScale

I don't understand this message:

> error: (-215) !empty() in function cv::CascadeClassifier::detectMultiScale

Here is my code so far:

```
import cv2

CAM_ID = (0)

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(CAM_ID)

if cap.isOpened() == False: 
    print ('Can\'t open the CAM(%d)' % (CAM_ID))
    exit()

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier("haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")

while(True):
   
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    grayframe = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    grayframe = cv2.equalizeHist(grayframe)

    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(grayframe, 1.1, 3, 0, (30, 30))
        for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(frame,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),3, 4, 0)
   

    cv2.imshow('Face',frame)

   
    if cv2.waitKey(10) >= 0:
        break;


cv2.namedWindow('Face')
cap.release()
cv2.destroyWindow('Face')
```

Comment: Look at the [source code](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/3.2.0/modules/objdetect/src/cascadedetect.cpp#L1681). This calls the [`empty`](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/3.2.0/modules/objdetect/src/cascadedetect.cpp#L888) method of the `CascadeClassifierImpl`. That hints at the classifier XML not loading correctly. | Your code lacks any kind of error checking. Both loading of the XML as well as reading frames can fail. You need to handle that.

Answer (score 0):

You can reference the link http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/tutorials/objdetect/cascade_classifier/cascade_classifier.html

Please check the `cv2.CascadeClassifier` return value. Make sure the `haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml` exist.